# Accessing a cookie value in an ASP.NET Core MVC Razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I set a cookie using JavaScript when the user clicks a button:

```
document.cookie = "menuSize=Large";
```

I need to access this cookie in razor syntax so I can output the correct styles at the top of _Layout.cshtml every time the user changes pages:

```
    @{
        if (cookie == "Large")
        {
            <style>
LARGE STYLES
            </style>
        }
        else
        {
            <style>
SMALL STYLES
            </style>
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, is it important to put the value in a cookie? why you dont put it in a viewbag? so you can access it easily. As i understand here, you click a button, set cookie and load view, so you have a postback. then, as i just mentioned, why you dont put the value in a viewbag and catch it in razor. Or use Request.Cookies, it will be then: @Request.Cookies

Comment: What is your question? You don't know how to access a cookie? [Request.Cookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx)

Answer (score 17):

You can use this approach to get the cookie value.  Also ensure your cookie domain path is root.  Also you can write some helper method to get cookie value in C#.

```
@{
        if (Context.Request.Cookies["menuSize"].Value== "Large")
        {
            <style>
                LARGE STYLES
            </style>
        }
        else
        {
            <style>
                SMALL STYLES
            </style>
        }
 }
```

Comment: For some reason intellisense wasn't recognizing Request.Cookies. I ended up getting it to work with Context.Request. Is this because I am using ASP.NET MVC Core?

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to the headers and manually pull out my cookie THAT IS CREATED/SET ON THE CLIENT:

```
//HACK ridiculous i have to do all this instead of just getting the cookie from the cookies collection
var cookieFromHeaderString = (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"]).FirstOrDefault();

if (cookieFromHeaderString != null)
{

    string[] strArray = cookieFromHeaderString.Split(new string[] { "; " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string whCookie = strArray.Where(m => m.StartsWith("vpWH=")).FirstOrDefault();

    if (whCookie != null)
    {
        int start = whCookie.IndexOf("=") + 1;
        string cookieValue = whCookie.Substring(start);

        string[] whArray = cookieValue.Split(' ');

        int viewportWidth = 0;
        int viewportHeight = 0;

        if (whArray.Length == 2)
        {
            int.TryParse(whArray[0], out viewportWidth);
            int.TryParse(whArray[1], out viewportHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and did it:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

@{

    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["menuSize"].Value == "Large")
    {
        <style>
            LARGE STYLES
        </style>
    }

}
```